# Calculate DOS with Quantum Espresso and ASE

Tags: quantum-espresso, atomic-simulation-environment

I am unable to do a Quantum Espresso "nscf" calculation using ASE. I have created a "mwe" to show the problem, followed by the output. I will be grateful if someone helps me solve the problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ase.io as aio
from ase.calculators.espresso import Espresso
from ase.constraints import ExpCellFilter
from ase.dft.dos import DOS
from ase.optimize import BFGS

structure = aio.read("Fe_mp-13_symmetrized.cif")
pseudolst = {"Fe": "Fe.pbe-spn-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF"}

input_data = {
    "nspin": 2,
    "degauss": 0.04,
    'occupations': 'smearing',
    'smearing': 'gaussian',
}
structure.magmom = '3.0'
calc = Espresso(
    pseudopotentials=pseudolst,
    tstress=True,
    tprnfor=True,
    input_data=input_data,
    crystal_coordinates=True,
)
structure.calc = calc
ucf = ExpCellFilter(structure)
opt = BFGS(ucf, trajectory="structure.traj", restart="structure.restart")
opt.run(fmax=0.025)
structure.get_potential_energy()
dos = DOS(calc)
```

This is giving error:

```
python mwe.py
/home/rudra/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ase/calculators/espresso.py:170: FutureWarning: Espresso calculator is being restructured.  Please use e.g. Espresso(profile=EspressoProfile(argv=['mpiexec', 'pw.x'])) to customize command-line arguments.
  warnings.warn(compatibility_msg, FutureWarning)
      Step     Time          Energy          fmax
BFGS:    0 20:30:39    -8965.356995         6.760408
BFGS:    1 20:30:48    -8966.058114         0.045096
BFGS:    2 20:30:58    -8966.058212         0.146969
BFGS:    3 20:31:09    -8966.058147         0.027810
BFGS:    4 20:31:18    -8966.058162         0.018795
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rudra/Projects/ASE/QE/mwe.py", line 31, in <module>
    dos = DOS(calc)
          ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rudra/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ase/dft/dos.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.e_skn = np.array([[calc.get_eigenvalues(kpt=k, spin=s)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rudra/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ase/dft/dos.py", line 34, in <listcomp>
    self.e_skn = np.array([[calc.get_eigenvalues(kpt=k, spin=s)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rudra/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ase/dft/dos.py", line 34, in <listcomp>
    self.e_skn = np.array([[calc.get_eigenvalues(kpt=k, spin=s)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rudra/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ase/calculators/abc.py", line 92, in get_eigenvalues
    return eigs[kpt, spin]
           ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1
```

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I've now removed your Google Drive link, because of this policy: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/393/5 Please replace the file accordingly!